# Two ORDER BY clauses and a LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

This is some sorting: I have a table with ids, names and ratings.  I want to list the 10 best items based on ratings, that's fine:

```
SELECT id FROM items ORDER BY ratings DESC LIMIT 10
```

But now here comes the hard part: I want to list the 10 best items based on ratings but order them alphabetically.  I tried

```
SELECT id FROM items ORDER BY ratings DESC, names ASC LIMIT 10
```

and

```
SELECT id FROM items ORDER BY names ASC, ratings DESC  LIMIT 10
```

but neither gives the desired result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT id, names
   FROM items 
   ORDER BY ratings DESC
   LIMIT 10
   ) t
ORDER BY names
```

*EDIT: Further Explanation*

Your original query sorts by ratings DESC, and then by names -- it would only sort the names with the same ratings. So if two items had the same rating, then you'd get those 2 sorted by name. It's going to sort all your records by rating *first*, and then by name afterwards (within the same ratings).

Comment: but why original query not working, I waited to see some reason in the answer :)

Comment: @Akam -- the original query sorts by ratings DESC, and then by names -- it would only sort the names with the same ratings.  So if two items had the same rating, then you'd get those 2 sorted by name.  It's going to sort all your records by rating first, and then by name afterwards.  Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Thanks any way, i am not asked that question, I just want you to explain

Comment: @Akam -- no worries, good to add to the post and glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, name, rating
FROM
    (SELECT id, name, rating FROM items ORDER BY ratings LIMIT 10) t
ORDER BY name
```

This will take top 10 by `rating`, and then sort by `name`.

Your queries are incorrect because: *They sorts rows by names and then by ratings (or in oposite order), taking top10 after the sort is performed*. You need to make the first sort, take top 10 and then sort these 10 results using second column values.